# Create a new windows service using New-Service cmdlet

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I want to create a windows service using powershell cmdlet New-Service. I cannot use nssm or any other executable. The problem is there is very less documentation about New-Service and also I know there has to be a specific set of steps and specific structure of code to create a service which actually runs when started. I tried many times but this is not working.

```
function OnStart()
{
    [Int32]$i = 0
    while( $i -lt 12)
    {
        $i++
        "Start Function Hello world !`n" | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\tripa\OneDrive\Desktop\Test.txt -Append

    }



}

function OnStop()
{
    "Stop Function " | Out-file   -FilePath C:\Users\tripa\OneDrive\Desktop\Test.txt -Append
}
```

This is the code which I want to change as a service (filename is script.ps1). But I am not allowed to use nssm or any other software. Just powershell. Can anyone help please ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While it is theoretically possible to run a PowerShell script as a service, this would be quite difficult, as there are no provisions for it within PowerShell itself. There is a reason there are many projects out there that provide service wrapper code for things that don't normally run as services themselves. You could try getting things up and running with a bit of C# code (which you can compile using `Add-Type`) by deriving from the `ServiceBase` class. Even this is quite a big project. `New-Service` itself cannot get you there at all; that merely registers an executable.

Comment: Strongly consider whether something simpler like a scheduled task wouldn't also be good enough for your purposes; it can run on startup, login or periodically. If you really need a "proper" Windows service I can only recommend you do not try to do so through a PowerShell script, especially not if this is a solution you intend to distribute to other machines; such a solution would not be very stable or secure. Not being "allowed" to use executables isn't really a good excuse. You don't have to use software that installs, per se, but at the very least a simple service wrapper.

Comment: Hi there !
For your second last statement , I forgot to  mention by  "not allowed" I meant exactly the same thing you were referring to. If this solution is intended on a different machine, it is a security issue.
As per your last statement, it is better if I use C# for the same, as there a some .NET classes which take care of these cases ?

Comment: Basically, to run a service in .NET, derive from the [`ServiceBase`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase) class and call `ServiceBase.Run` on startup to run as a service. In theory this is accessible from PowerShell as well, in practice this is difficult because you would have to have overridden methods call into PowerShell  functions. I've never tried something like this so I don't know if it even works without causing nasty issues with reentrancy and whatnot. To run this "service", you'd have to register `powershell.exe` itself with the script as argument.